# c# Background worker does not exit

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm using a background worker to listen to UDP and then doing the processing. I want to exit when I click on button2

```
  public snmpmain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backsnmp = new BackgroundWorker();
        backsnmp.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backsnmp_DoWork);
        backsnmp.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
               (backsnmp_ProgressChanged);
        backsnmp.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _startsnmp = true;
        backsnmp.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;


    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        this.backsnmp.RunWorkerAsync();
      }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
       /* it executes this when button2 is pressed but nothing happens. I can receive the UDP packets the dowork hasn't stopped*/
    {
        _startsnmp = false;
        backsnmp.CancelAsync();
        listBox1.Items.Add("SNMP Stopped");

        }

 void backsnmp_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add (e.UserState as String);        
     }

  void backsnmp_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("SNMP Stopped");
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

  void backsnmp_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        backsnmp.ReportProgress(0, "Initializing SNMP Listener on Port:" + port + "...");
             UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(port);
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

            while (true)
            {

                if (backsnmp.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }


                   Thread.Sleep(100);


                    backsnmp.ReportProgress(0, "Waiting for messages....");

       packet = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);   // When I press button2 it's right here


                  // do some work here
```

It goes and executes button2_Click when I click on button2, but nothing really happens. The dowork isn't cancelled. I can still receive the packets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# cancelling DoWork of background worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826096/c-sharp-cancelling-dowork-of-background-worker)

Comment: @wudzik: but that doesn't really suggest how to abort without using the abortablebackgrounder

Comment: if you need udp async then you should use [`UdpClient.BeginReceive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx) instead of the background worker.

Comment: Tip for using `xxxBegin` method: If you like to get further packets after the first recieve you should within your callback call `BeginReceive()` again.

Comment: You'll also need to un-block the Receive() call.  You do so by closing the socket.  Note that this is required no matter whether you use BGW or use BeginReceive().  Be prepared to catch the ObjectDisposedException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listener.Receive` blocks until data is received. Hence your cancellation isn't recognized at all.

What you could do is either using `BeginReceive` (and get rid of the BackgroundWorker) or try to make `listener` a class field and dispose it when cancelling. The latter should leave the blocking receive with an exception though. Well - or send a message to the listener yourself after cancelling (which obviously will wake the receiver as well).

Comment: Based on your advise I have changed it to BeginReceive. Can you please advise now How do I implement stopping the begin receive, as it's in a separate asycnch thread.

Comment: Dispose the UDPClient and catch the exception in the callback from EndReceive.

Comment: Disposing would be done in the button control and how would I catch the exception. Would you mind giving me a short example. I'm confused at this. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I told you, that you catch the exception where you call EndReceive. The "BeginReceive thread" returns to the ThreadPool. You'll find examples in the documentation (MSDN) -- Please try to learn about the async IO pattern - I'm sorry, but it's beyond a question site to teach it! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60097/The-NET-Asynchronous-I-O-Design-Pattern maybe a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, I have sorted this out. I'm doing a boolean on the button control and then checking for this in the beginrecieve. If it's true I dispose the udpclient in the beginrecieve callback. Thanks for your advise, it really helped.+1 for this.